# bringSubViewToFront not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, subview

I have an image created in storyboard. And I added an button programmatically and added to view.

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(30,30,30,30);
button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
[imageView addSubview:button];
```

These two are overlapping and button behind is invisible, but its action can be performed. I try to bring this button over image using,

```
[imageView bringSubViewToFront:button];
```

But its not working.

Comment: It seems you are not setting button frame.

Comment: I already set the frame,just missed to mention.

Comment: If your button is not dynamic then you can directly add it on imageview from storyboard instead of adding it programatically. Else create image view programatically and add button after that it will work.

Comment: you have to addSubview your button in your view not in imageView.

Comment: Did you set text in button ? and make sure it is not hidden ? and also make sure you have added image view in view ?

Comment: @Wolverine, I take  ofcare all these stuff, and I am pretty clear about it.

Comment: Then try to print all the subviews of your views and check button is there or not.. because if you have taken care of all these tings then it must work.

Comment: amit_donga said is right - change this [imageView addSubview:button]; to [self.view addSubview:button];

Comment: Debug View Hierarchy  in Xcode can help you, where the button is placed in the view hierarchy and what is blocking its interaction https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 0):

there is no chance that button will be behind imageView if u write so .there must be a time u adjust two views' relation after u add button the the imageView.

Answer (score -1):

After create button programatically and put that button in subview of imageview, Make sure make your imageview property Userinteraction Enabled TRUE.
Use this statement, hopefully it works:

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
```